# Regular expression for mobile number error in case 1 1 1 1 1 1

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression for mobile number validation. I have tried below regular expression. If I enter `1 1 1 1 1 1` it will not be accepted. Will you please help to to find what is my mistake in regular expression.

Regular expression is: `^\s*\+?\s*([0-9][\s-]*){6,}$`

Comment: Have you checked your current regular expression? In Python it gives me this error: "Invalid regular expression: multiple repeat". This seems to be the problem: \s*+

Comment: no it's not duplicate of it. i don't want special char in expression. i even don't want space.

Comment: I assume the mentioned "multiple repeat" isn't really that, but an option to allow a initial `+` with the escape character missing. If it's so, your original regex only needs to escape it, i.e. ` ^\s*\+?\s*([0-9][\s-]*){6,}$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex like this ::::

**/^[+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im**

Here i makes the expression case-insensitive and m performs multi-line searches

Or

**^([0-9]*){6,}$**

Check any number with this regex

Comment: Thank you but i don't want + and multiline

Comment: But that's the perfect way for that because user can not write wrong format number

Comment: /^(\+\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{10}$/    <<<< this will also do the trick but + and - will be used for that ..

Comment: It will be included in country ISDcode field. so i want only number. I also don't want it only for india

Comment: ^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\ -]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}|(\d[ -]?){10}\d$ 
try out this one

Comment: Thank you ^([0-9]*){6,}$ works for me

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion to match "1 1 1 1 1 1" would be:

```
^\s*([0-9\s-]){6,}$
```

The error in your regular expression is the multiple repeat at its beginning:

```
\s*+
```

Check the result on [pythex](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5E%5Cs*(%5B0-9%5Cs-%5D)%7B6%2C%7D%24&test_string=1%201%201%201%201%201&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).